# Deliver Multiple assets in single publish Url

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

We are proposing to use Azure Media Services (WAMS) for pre-recorded audio streaming.

Currently we can create assets in media services for audio data.

Suppose if we need to play multiple assets when we deliver the content then how can we do the same?

Currently each asset has separate publish URL from azure portal
How can we generate single publish URL to point to multiple assets?

Also how to play multiple assets in random sequence for each different request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have single Publish URL for multiple assets. Each Asset has associated publish URLs. Each Publish URL is also associated with specific Access Policy.

What you want to achieve is called PlayList. And, if PlayLists might be supported from products like IceCast or other, they are not supported in Azure Media Services.

You have to maintain playlists within your media application. And populate playlist items with the publish URLs of the Media Assets you want in each playlist.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for feedback if we have to implement playlist then can we have IceCast support in azure? Or can you propose any solution with sample demonstration. We really appreciate your response.

Comment: Also can we use IIS media services web playlist feature to achieve the same as follows http://www.iis.net/learn/media/web-playlists/web-playlists-for-iis-7-creating-a-simple-playlist

Comment: You can use both scenarios - IceCast on a Linux VM or IIS Media Services Playlist on Windows VM. But then you have to maintain everything on your own. While with Azure Media Services and very little effort to create Playlist with your code you will have much less complexity and code to maintain. IceCast is open source (GPL) product. You have to search for paid support for it, and Microsoft will not provide it!